# How do I make sure a path between two nodes runs through all the connections of an intermediate node?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I may be trying to solve a problem in the stupidest way possible, so please correct me if there's an easier way to do this. I'm trying to model some conditionals via a graph. In this case, we have people and health plans.

Let's say that to qualify for health plan A, you have to live in a certain place and be full-time, or you can live in another place and be full or part time.

The way I'm modeling this is with a series of paths between a person and a plan, with the last node before the plan being a "Condition" node. I think this structure allows for AND and OR relationships. More than one Condition linking to a plan represents ORs (You can be in one state OR you can be in a different state AND be full time).

Here's a picture of a path between one person (yellow node: "FTai" don't ask about the name) and a plan (green node).
[image]

The red node represents the Condition, and the rule is that this person can utilize this health plan if all there is a path from the person to the Condition through all of the Condition's incoming connections. How do I write a query that, for a particular person, collects all the plans they can access?

For instance, for the other person ("Hai"), the query shouldn't produce the plan because they aren't connected to the Full Time node, which feeds into the Connection.

Comment: Are status and location nodes the only nodes that will link to condition nodes? Or are there different kinds of links to conditions apart from these? Also, are all the paths from a person node to a condition node going in the same direction?

Comment: Also, are different condition nodes going to link to the same health plan, or is this 1:1?

Comment: Good questions. I'm aiming to build a system that can be kind of flexible, so I don't think status and location nodes will be the only ones linking into a condition node. At present they are, but I anticipate that will change either as I discover other circumstances or as the modeled system changes.

As to direction of relationships, I'm setting this up, so the paths can all be in the same direction, I think.

Finally, it won't be 1:1. I anticipate having one Condition for each "OR" circumstance. Multiple Conditions accommodate ORs and multiple links to a Condition allows for ANDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question.

Provided that the relationships present are all meaningful to the evaluation of the condition (for example, no :ONCE_LIVED_IN relationship to Hawaii or similar that might cause the condition to wrongly evaluate to true), and provided the relationship direction from a person to a plan is all one-way, with no other outgoing relationships that might derail a path into an irrelevant subgraph, it should be fairly straight forward to form your query.

Here's a creation query for the graph in your description:

```
create (p:Person{name:'FTai'}), (p2:Person{name:'Hai'})
create (hi:State{name:'Hawaii'})
create (con:Condition)
create (hhc:Plan{name:'Hawaii Healthcare'})
create (ft:EmploymentStatus{name:'Full Time'})
create (pt:EmploymentStatus{name:'Part Time'})
create (con)-[:ALLOWS]->(hhc)
create (ft)-[:REQUIRED_BY]->(con)
create (hi)-[:REQUIRED_BY]->(con)
create (p)-[:HAS_STATUS]->(ft)
create (p)-[:LIVES_IN]->(hi)
create (p2)-[:HAS_STATUS]->(pt)
create (p2)-[:LIVES_IN]->(hi)
```

Here's a query that starts at a :Person and follows outgoing relationships until it reaches a :Condition. From there, for each :Condition matched, we collect the distinct last relationships from those paths into that :Condition (should be :REQUIRED_BY relationships), and compare that to the number of incoming :REQUIRED_BY relationships into the :Condition. If the number of relationships are the same, then we've met every :REQUIRED_BY relationship into the :Condition, and can return the connected :Plan.

```
MATCH (p:Person{name:'FTai'})-[r*..5]->(con:Condition)
WITH con, COLLECT(DISTINCT LAST(r)) as metRequirements
WHERE SIZE(metRequirements) = SIZE(()-[:REQUIRED_BY]->(con))
MATCH (con)-[:ALLOWS]->(plan:Plan)
RETURN DISTINCT plan
```

EDIT

My creation query didn't include the :DEFINED_AS relationships between states and employment status, and the presence of those relationships will cause the query I provided to match improperly (so Hai will wrongly fulfill the condition).

There are a few ways around this kind of obstacle. You can do whitelisting or blacklisting. For whitelisting, you'll need to provide every valid relationship to traverse in the variable-length relationship.

Blacklisting will likely be easier, if there are relationship types that should never be traversed for your query. Here's an updated version of the query that will work even if the :DEFINED_AS relationships are in place:

```
// you can add to the blacklist as needed, and change to a parameter
WITH ['DEFINED_AS'] as blacklist
MATCH (p:Person{name:'Hai'})-[r*..5]->(con:Condition)
WHERE NONE(rel in r WHERE TYPE(rel) in blacklist)
WITH con, COLLECT(DISTINCT LAST(r)) as metRequirements
WHERE SIZE(metRequirements) = SIZE(()-[:REQUIRED_BY]->(con))
MATCH (con)-[:ALLOWS]->(plan:Plan)
RETURN DISTINCT plan
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out. It seems to scratch the itch pretty successfully. I'd also be interested in knowing whether, based on your experience, you think this is a good way to go about modeling this. By good I mean, any combination of "the best", "sensible", "manageable", etc. If you have any critique, or alternate approaches, I'd be interested to hear them. - Thanks

Comment: I tried it out, but the same query also allows access for the other Person in the graph ("Hai"). I'm still working it through, but I think it's because a separate relationship between the State and the EmployementStatus (which is part of another record-keeping project) allows the traversal to go from Hai, to HI, to Full Time, and thence to the Condition. I can probably limit the types of relationships it travels or I can maybe use shortest paths to exclude those other paths.

Comment: Seems pretty good to me. The things I'd watch out for as the model evolves are new outgoing relationships, and making sure they don't end up creating paths to conditions that aren't meant to be matched. If you do have to set up relationships that aren't meant to be followed for this kind of query, then you'll need to explicitly include all outgoing path types you want to follow in your variable-length relationship, and that's kind of a pain to keep up to date as your model changes.

Comment: Ah, yeah, the reason mine works is I didn't create the DEFINED_AS relationships, those were going to be problematic in the matching (basically the issue mentioned in the above comment). Do you really need those?

Comment: Looks like you do need those. I provided a modified query that uses a blacklist of relationship types, so those won't be traversed in the match.

Comment: Thanks for all the help thinking about this. I can see a world in which I add a property to all the relationships such that relationships that should be part of the connection between a person and the plan has a property like "is_benefit_pathway:true". I'm also wondering if maybe this isn't the way to solve this particular problem.

Comment: That can work too, though you'll be using the ALL() function on relationships instead of NONE(). Property access tends to be slower than reading and comparing types, though I imagine your queries will be limited to a person or smaller group of people, and your paths shouldn't be too long, so it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't see the complexity of your query but how about something like this:

```
match (state:State)-[:REQUIRED_BY]->(and:Condition)<-[:REQUIRED_BY]-(status:EmploymentStatus)
with state,status,and
match (status)<-[:HAS_STATUS]-(person:Person)-[:LIVES_IN]->(state)
with person, and
match (and)-[:ALLOWS]->(plan:Plan)
return person, plan
```

Comment: That works for this particular example case. But what about :Conditions that only have :State requirements, but not :EmploymentStatus requirements, or vice versa? What if the model is enhanced with new types of nodes and requirements besides :State and :EmploymentStatus? The complexity isn't so much in the example model, but in finding an approach that will work as the model itself grows more complex.